# jquery progressbar with value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want two progressbar with value specified in the data-value,but both values is same

html

```
<div>
<div class="p" data-value="54"></div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="p" data-value="45"></div>
 </div>
```

jquery

```
var t=$(".p").closest("div").data('value');
alert(t);
$(".p").progressbar({
value:t
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s7uxtbu7/9/

Comment: why do you use closest() here? its parent element doesnt have data property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over them and bind `progressbar` individually. Use:

```
$(".p").each(function(){
 var t=$(this).data('value');
   $(this).progressbar({
     value:t
   });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cw0r4w96/)**

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
var t=$(".p").closest("div").data('value');
```

use this

```
var t=$(".p").data('value');
```